# Brake sensor wire

Tags: brakes, sensor

I have an electric bike, and I am looking for an electric wire that is attached to the brake lever.
how can I get it?

regards.
Hussein Talib.

Comment: Hi Hussein and welcome to SE. Unfortunately you have provided very little details, such that the only (unhelpful) answer one can give is "you get the wire in the shop". Can you perhaps [edit] your post, provide a photo, a name and model of your bike **and** some information on where you've looked so far? Others can then actually provide helpful suggestions on where or how you can look for the part you're looking for.

Comment: With many brands of e-bike component, the answer is "with considerable difficulty" even once you've identified the actual part

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're after a brake lever with an integrated sensor to cut motor power when you actuate either hand brake.

[image]

Try search terms like `bicycle brake lever with electric switch` .

Some brake levers have two sensor wires - one for motor-cut and a second sensor for "activate regenerative braking" so check your ebike's options and what it is capable of.

There exist instructions for adding such a switch to an existing brake lever.  However brakes are important and you don't want a home-brew brake lever to fail when you need it.  I would purchase brake parts new.

Comment: I have managed to buy a replacement switch cable assembly for that lever (which I think is what the OP wants). I had to go to the bike importer at the time, because there was no independent reseller of tektro OEM e-bike parts. That should have improved by now. It's quite clever. There's a magnet in the lever and a reed switch embedded in plastic underneath. But it's let down by the flimsy plastic around the fixing screws - and on the one I dealt with, by the assembler strapping the wire to the brake cable housing so close and tight that using the barrel adjuster strained the plastic.

Comment: @ChrisH I have a good selection of heatshrink tubing and one of the primarily uses is for reinforcing where cords exit, that kind of thing.

Comment: I used some on the repair, but the damage to the original was that the rings of plastic around the screw holes on the switch snapped. There just wasn't enough material to resist the force caused by the too-tight assembly after a routine adjustment of the barrel adjuster (and that bike wore its original pads fast)